# Detect timezone using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

i would like to know if there is any possibility of getting timezone in format: gmt+05:30 delhi chennai mumbai kolkata.i need to do this in javascript and the timezone should be based on browser location.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091372/getting-the-clients-timezone-in-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this question is a bit long and requires other libraries to function properly. Have a look at this website:
https://css-tricks.com/localizing-times-in-javascript/

Hope it helps! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `getTimezoneOffset()` method to return the time difference between UTC time and your local time, in minutes.

Below an example on how to return the timezone difference between UTC and Local Time:

```js
var d = new Date()
var n = d.getTimezoneOffset();
console.log(n);
```

[More information here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset).